# How do I use a DataTable with SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a complex reporting requirement to create a Re-Order Manufacturing Materials report.  The data is coming from three different databases: two Oracle databases via ODBC, and one SQL Server database.  The user needs to pass in a date range for the parameters.  What I would like to do combine and perform business logic over the data in C# and then pass the data to the report.  This would be an easy task in Active Reports but SSRS is all the client has.

How do I have a parameter screen and also pass the data table to an SSRS report?

The only thing I can think of right now is to create a custom ASP.NET parameter screen, gather the data, save the data to a table, and then run the report.  I would also have to have a cron job to clear out old data from the report table.  This is a kludge to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set up [linked servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280106) to the Oracle databases from Sql Server, then you can just join across the servers in SQL and create a single dataset from your three databases.

You could turn your C# program into a [web service that returns XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#XML) and use that as your data source in your report.

Another, slightly more involved, way to do it that I have used is to create a [custom data processing extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to provide the data. While this is a bit more heavy lifting up front, if you have an API that you need to query rather than a database (for example, RESTful web services) then this is a powerful solution.